# Spinner populated shows wrong characters

Tags: android, text, spinner

thanks for your help

I'm trying populate a spinner with data from an embedded database, and everything seems right:

```
 public ArrayList<String[]> getCountries()
{
    ArrayList<String[]> array = new ArrayList<>();
    String columnas[] = new String[]{"COUNTRY","COUNTRYCODE"};
    Cursor c = db.query("countryCodT",columnas,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String[] obj = new String[2];
            obj[0]=c.getString(0);
            obj[1]=c.getString(1);
            array.add(obj);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return array;
}
```

with this code the spinner is populated:

```
public void popSpinnerC(){
    BDCountries bdCountries = new BDCountries(this);
    final ArrayList<String[]> dataGot = bdCountries.getCountries();
    ArrayAdapter<String[]> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dataGot);
    spnCountry.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spnCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String listId = Integer.toString(i);
            strCounty = listId + dataGot.get(i)[0] + dataGot.get(i)[1];   
            msgData.setText(strCounty);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```

the spinner text shown is wrong, the data amount is correct, when something is selected is shown the right information in a text view with test purposes, how can I correct it?
[Results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP5sk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner option list is a list of string arrays rather than strings so it is printing `toString()` of each string array as a spinner item.

Look at your `getCountries()` method.  It is returning `ArrayList<String[]>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @javivar please mark this as the answer if it helped you out